# Problema de scroll en css

Tags: css, imagen, scroll

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Dragons </title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="img/castle.jpg" alt="castillo">
    <main>

    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Acá se ven las barritas que me dicen que debo hacer el scroll]

Lo que quiero es saber cómo hago para evitar tener este scroll y que la imagen tome el 100% del espacio de la pantalla y no más que eso. Gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podemos ocultar el scroll de abajo con la propiedad `overflow-x`, que justamente se basa en controlar la barra de desplazamiento del elemento que desborda del ancho de la pantalla, entonces, podemos ocultarlo con la propiedad `overflow-x: hidden;`.

Veamos un ejemplo, encerremos en un `div` a tu imagen, que le llamaremos `imagen`:

```
<div class="imagen">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" alt="castillo">
</div>
```

Ahora, tu imagen, se sobresaldrá de tu div debido a su ancho, entonces para ocultar la barra de desplazamiento de abajo, le damos la propiedad `overflow-x: hidden`:

```
.imagen {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Y el resultado vendría a ser el siguiente:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.imagen {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagen">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" alt="castillo">
</div>
```

Ahora, a mi opinión, es una mala práctica darles anchos y alturas fijas a la imagen, ya que tenemos que tener en cuenta en los casos de las pantallas que tienen otras resoluciones, la imagen se verá estirada, dando una mala perspectiva al usuario.

En este caso podemos indicar que la imagen ocupe el `100%` de todo el ancho de la pantalla y sin una altura fija, así la altura se adaptará siempre al ancho, teniendo el siguiente resultado:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" alt="castillo">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu comentario fue de gran ayuda 

Comment: @santiago Me alegro, recuerda verificar la respuesta si te sirvió dándole al ✔️ para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que las imágenes en html no solo tienen el tamaño de la imagen, si no que también tienes que tener en cuenta el tamaño de los bordes, cambiando el display en tu css ya estaría solucionado

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Dragons </title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="img/castle.jpg" alt="castillo">
    <main>

    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

De todas formas te recomiendo que crees una nueva clase para la imagen y la apliques solo a esta imagen ya que si no este css se aplicará a todas las imágenes de tu html

Comment: no conocía la propiedad display

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debe usar es overflow:hidden en el selector universal para eliminar la barra de desplazamiento tanto horizontal y vertical.

Codigo:

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

si solo quieres eliminar solo la barra horizontal bastaria el colocar overflow-x: hidden.

Codigo:

```
img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;   
}
```